# Get last day of previous month using Javascript or MomentJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I have fetched first and last day of the month in MomentJS like this:

```
 var startDate = ConvertToNewDateFormat(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0));
        var endDate = ConvertToNewDateFormat(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1));
```

This returns lets say:

```
2016-05-01 -> start

2016-05-31 -> end
```

What I need is day before 05-01  and day after 31.05 (in general for every month like that), i.e. last day of previous month and first day of next month... How can I do this ??

Comment: Can't you subtract a month? http://codeply.com/go/Do8iXaEJvf

Comment: i.e. `moment().subtract(1, 'days');` and `moment().add(1, 'days');`

Answer (score 0):

```
  start=moment().startOf('month');
  end=moment().endOf('month');
  lastDayOfPrevMonth =moment(start).subtract(1,'day')
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxnwgh06/3/)